# Sorting numbers in JTable

Tags: java, swing, sorting, numbers, jtable

Please, could anyone see why this code still refuse to use my comparator ?
This is all code relative to userTable object + I have mouse and key listener there, but I think it is not affecting sorting.

```
private TableRowSorter trs;

public constructor() {
initComponents();
...
trs = new TableRowSorter<>(userTable.getModel());

    class IntComparator implements Comparator {

        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            System.out.println("comparing");
            Integer int1 = (Integer) o1;
            Integer int2 = (Integer) o2;
            return int1.compareTo(int2);
        }

    }

    trs.setComparator(0, new IntComparator());
    userTable.setRowSorter(trs);
...
}

private void initComponents() {
...
userTable = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            @Override
            public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
                return renderer;
            }
        };
...
userTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ID", "count", "null"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Object.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, false, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });

}
```

It keeps doing RADIX sort and also message "comparing" s never shown.
Thank you.

Comment: *".. with NetBeans"*  Do it exactly the same way you'd do it with Eclipse, or IntelliJ, or from code written using Notepad.

Comment: You don't need any specific comparator to sort integers like this, since your comparator sorts according to the natural order of integers.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse, or IntelliJ so no idea how I would do it there :D Anyway, I don't see your point sorry.

Comment: Well, it is not. Sorted field> 1136,636,678,684,799

Comment: Why don't you use jTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)?

Comment: I did. Still RADIX sort, ignoring data type Integer of first two columns.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Here's an SSCCE which works, just by using the automatic row sorter: https://gist.github.com/4380063

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, demonstrated custom `Comparator` instead of built in `RowSorter`, and non empty `JTable`

Comment: @Maroš Košina JTableHeader has added KeyBinding (F2 or 8??? for built in RowSorter), override that for your Comparator

Comment: I got through many examples, also from oracle, but unhelpfully for my problem. When I compiled them as stand alone they worked. @mKorbel: It would be useless make SSCCE from my problem, because my problem is connected with NetBeans generated code, so I had to pull out just relative parts of code. If I would make SSCCE it would work maybe, but wouldn't solve the problem.

Comment: well then take as useless all comments here, problem(s) is/are elsewhere, somewhere in rest of code, by default similair code work for me, sorry your issue ...

Comment: @Maroš Košina [everything are here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+jtable+sorting)

Comment: OMG ! I just found my problem. Feel stupid now :D I fill table from DB using JDBC. I detected data type on read TIMESTAMP and nothing else. By default loaded object was STRING. So I set INT on table, but filled it with STRING object. Thank you for your interest and exuce my blindness. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that table was filled from DB using JDBS, where I did not set proper data type.
Table column itself was set as integer, or float, but data readed from DB was considered for string.

```
switch (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i + 1)) {
                        case 93: //DATE
                            rowData[i] = rs.getDate(i + 1).toString() + "> " + rs.getTime(i + 1);
                            break;
                        default:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
                            break;
                    }
```

New code looks like this.

```
switch (rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i + 1)) {
                        case 93:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getDate(i + 1).toString() + "> " + rs.getTime(i + 1);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getInt(i + 1);
                            break;
                        case -5:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getLong(i + 1);
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getFloat(i + 1);
                            break;
                        default:
                            rowData[i] = rs.getString(i + 1);
                            break;
                    }
```

Jtable has default row sorterer builded by checkbox in netbeans :D

Comment: search for ResultSetTableModel or TableFromDatabase

Answer (score 0):

http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setComparator(int, java.util.Comparator)

1. You probably need to call "sort"
2. You probably need to specify "1" as starting column (not sure, just a hunch)

Comment: sort is called by default. It just was called on other sorter object. Anyway I have solved my problem, see comments on question. Thank you for your effort.